# Backup of images

Tags: backup, rsync, git

I've just installed a Ubuntu for a file server.
It will share a folder (samba) and employees of my company will save photos on that.
Currently the total amount of the photos is about 100GB and every day 20MB will be added.

My question is about backup plan. I want to backup the photos to a remote server using a cron job. I can think of 2 things.

1. rsync
2. git

Image files won't be changed so I think `rsync` will do, but people say I must keep all my data in `git`.

What would you do?

Comment: "But as people say, I must git all my data." No, people don't say that.

Comment: @ceejayoz Plenty of people say that. I say plenty of people are idiots though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't set your backup policy for you. You've already identified that rsync will do "what you need".

I don't know why you think you need to "git all your data"; git is a revision and source control tool, not a backup tool.

Comment: I realized that my question was so dumb. This question deserves the negatives. I apologize. I'll go with rsync. Thanks.